# Read system files on Android

Tags: android, file

I need to access files on the system, namely for obtaining information. File build.prop take out so

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/getprop").getInputStream();
```

I need a list of other files and how they read. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'll have `SecurityException`, because user, which is associated with your app has no permission to read this file. The only way to do this is to have a rooted device.

Comment: I agree with you, but how do I get root access?

Comment: It depends on phone model, but SO is not the place to discuss this. There are many tutorials in the Web.

Answer (score 0):

most of the files in `/system` you cannot access because it requires **ROOT**.